# How can i get output in postman?

Tags: automation, postman, web-api-testing

I am trying to get list of products from api. i requested url with get method and response code is 200. but how can i get to see list of products in postman?

https://url/Product/all

Comment: I am getting 404 for this request. Please share screenshots for better explanation.

Comment: {domain}​/Product​/GetProductById​/{id}

Comment: This isn't helping; I am not able to infer anything from this one liner. Share proper error screenshots in postman (you may cover the sensitive url part if required) please.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/nadP9A.jpg

Comment: i get 200 status code. but where i can get output

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are getting the response in HTML format; you just need to scroll down in the response body to see them. Change your response body format from HTML to JSON. You should be able to see the JSON.
[image]

Comment: yes i also did that but doesnt work

Comment: share screenshot of the response body after you made this change (make sure the api url is correct)

Comment: An http request will return HTML or JSON (or XML or ...) as the response body. Not both/ many. This dropdown only changes the formatting in Postman, not the nature of the response itself.

Comment: Then the issue must lie with the application itself as it is returning HTML instead of required JSON, which is why I wanted to see screenshots of the actual returned response to confirm. I presume the html is a default 404 page.
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXTaISAW/week-3-getting-html-response-from-the-postman-calling-api-gateway-proxy-url